# The method 'where' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: where(Closure: (Stop) => bool) Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 screens which I want to filter, but I have got this error:

```
The method 'where' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: where(Closure: (Stop) => bool)
```

I created the list for putting all filtered stops's value and trying to put it into the ListView, but I got this error. here on SO they said that i need to create these lines to achive my filtration goals:

```
 List<Stop> filtered = [];
    filtered = stops.where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();
```

But when I tried this, I got an error.

this is the both screens:

```
class Stops extends StatelessWidget {
  int stId;
  int mrId;
  String stTitle;
  Stops({this.stId, this.stTitle, this.mrId,});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Routes> routes = Provider.of<List<Routes>>(context).where((element) => element.mrId == mrId).toList();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: routes == null
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: routes.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(routes[index].mrTitle),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Stopin(
                               stId: routes[index].mrId,
                              )));
                    },
                  );
                }));
  }
}

class Stopin extends StatelessWidget {
final int stId;
  const Stopin({Key key, this.stId}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Stop> stops = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context);
    List<Stop> filtered = [];
    filtered = stops.where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();
    return  Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: stops == null
            ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: filtered.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(filtered[index].stTitle),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

**Side question:**
Also I was thinking if there is any way to filter both lists by its titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, you are calling a function `where` on a null Object, and that is not allowed.

stops is Nullable ?

Try :

```
List<Stop> = stops?.where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList() ?? [];
```

or

```
List<Stop> filtered = [];
if (stops != null) {
    filtered = stops.where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();
}
```